# Capacitor Monitoring

Tags: capacitor, charging

How would you monitor a bank of capacitor to tell if they are fully charged.  I would like to display the precent of they're current charged state using an LED bar graph.

Comment: Do you have a separate voltage that you can use as a reference?

Comment: This sounds VERY cool ill def be following this question.

Comment: Here's a start: http://www.national.com/mpf/LM/LM3916.html

Comment: Kellenjb, The reference voltage I was going to use would be the power supply voltage charging the capacitor.

Answer (score 3):

Charge of a cap is CV = Q.  Just measure V.  This is quite different than a battery, much simpler

Answer (score 2):

1. Build the [LM3916 example circuit](http://www.national.com/ds/LM/LM3916.pdf) and connect the input to your capacitors.
2. Adjust the LM3916 Vref so that the range matches the range you want to measure.

It already has a high-impedance buffer built-in, so it won't discharge the caps.

Comment: During charging wouldn't the LM3916 show a 100% full

Comment: No, capacitors don't charge like batteries.  The voltage on the capacitor is proportional to the energy it is storing, so it will work for both charging and discharging.